# What command makes your current working directory the "real" copy in git?

Tags: git, heroku

I'm having a hard time with git vocabulary.  I'm looking at a cheat sheet but I don't understand which command makes my repository copy exactly equal to my current working copy.  So I have what I want to push to Heroku on my PC and I want to make that copy all Heroku will see when I do the push.  What is the command?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a maximally condensed explanation to get you through the basics:

- `git commit -a`: records a snapshot of your working tree into a local *commit*. This still doesn't go to remote, and doesn't require network access. You may create as many separate commits as you like before publishing them.
- `git push`: publishes your commits to the remote server. If the remote has newer commits that would be clobbered by your push, the push will fail, and you will have to `pull`. (This is equivalent to how `svn commit` fails if there are more recent changes, in which case you must do an `svn update` and repeat the commit.)
- `git pull`: pulls remote commits into your local history and working tree. If you have unpushed old commits, this will also create a commit that merges (creates a hybrid of) the old and the new ones.

While this is just enough to get you started, I advise that you study a git book or article, because otherwise you will have problems later down the road. Whatever you are doing with git, your collaborators will certainly expect you to understand concepts such as merging, rebasing, branches, and diffs.

Comment: `git commit -a` won't cause any new files to be added to the repository. `git add -A :/` can be used before the `git commit` command to accomplish that, and makes use of commit's `-a` option unnecessary.

Comment: @qqx Well, a minimalistic cheat sheet can't cover everything. Once the OP's workflow begins to include adding new files, he'll have to read up on `git add`. `git add -A` is a very bad idea for a beginner because it will blindly add the various generated files to the repository. (Yes, one should use `.gitignore` to avoid that, but a beginner typically doesn't.)

Answer (score 0):

I really like this [visual cheatsheet](http://ndpsoftware.com/git-cheatsheet.html) and I point all newbies towards it.  It shows how each command affects the working tree, index, local, and remote repos.

A few things to note.  Your working copy (working tree in git parlance) is what you're currently editing on disk.  It may or may not represent the latest commit in the repository.  If you have all your changes committed (`git status` comes back clean), then `git push` is what you want to use to make Heroku's branch look like your branch.  I don't know how you've set this up, but I'm assuming your current branch is tracking the remote Heroku repository.

`git commit` records your changes, but `git push` and `git fetch` are used to share and retrieve changes.

Comment: What's amazing me right now is that after running `git commit`, `git status` shows differences.

Comment: @JoeEssey That's because you failed to pass the `-a` flag to `git commit`. See my cheat sheet.

Comment: @JoeEssey git is definitely different.  You need to get what you want into the index via `git add`, and then `git commit`.  If you haven't read it, [Pro Git](http://git-scm.com/book) is a good book to get started with.